# How to give general feedback to KLM?

Tags: klm

My wife and I recently flew with KLM and the experience was disappointing in several ways. I would like to give some feedback but I cannot find how to do so in their website. I am forced to select one of a few specific options and I cannot find a general feedback option.  There is a phone number but I fear that could be very time consuming. I was hoping for an email or web feedback option.

Additional detail:

I have logged into my Flying Blue account and entered my booking details. I have tried every option that I can find for feedback but all bring me to the same page which has a choice of just a few specific options. I have also tried web searches but they also bring me back to the same page.

We flew from the the UK to Warsaw via Amsterdam and back.

Comment: Sorry to say, but chances are high that they don't care. Even if you found a method to contact them, unless you are legally entitled to some kind of compensation, your complaint will most likely not result in anything more than a boilerplate response.

Comment: Yeah, I expected that but I thought that I could manage an email or web form.  As I said, I could not manage the effort of a phone call.

Comment: Type up your response in Notepad (or equivalent), then copy/paste it into the form for _every_ complaint type. Sure, they don't have a "general issue" category, so just spam it across all categories. Not your fault their system doesn't meet your specific need...

Comment: I suspect that everyone who receives it will react: that's not my area.

Comment: It's probably a clear message that they don't want your feedback if there's no feedback button.

Comment: We live in a strange world where writing some tirade on Twitter (oh, my bad, X, of course), and tagging KLM, may get you some actual attention from them.

Answer (score 7):

You can always send them a physical letter. Their [official address](https://www.klm.com/information/corporate/contact) is:

> KLM Royal Dutch Airlines
>
> P.O. Box 7700
>
> 1117 ZL Schiphol
>
> The Netherlands

I'd estimate any email feedback (if you can eventually find an email to send it to) will have a 0.01% chance of being acted on. Letters might actually be more effective in that regard, I'd give it a 0.05% chance of something being done in response, assuming the letter is sufficiently detailed and actionable.

Comment: I had considered that.  I can't decide whether it is worth the effort.  I am probably dreaming of a golden age when companies were interested in what their customers thought.

Comment: @badjohn the problem is that most customer feedback is trash and not worth responding to. You might have a legitimately good piece of feedback but I'd estimate 99% of all incoming complaints can be sent to /dev/null without impacting the company's profits.

Answer (score 6):

I contacted them through WhatsApp ([+31206490787](https://saudi.klm.com/contact/booking/help-online-booking)), at first a bot replied, then a human took over. I requested the customer servicer email address, and this was their response:

[image: WA response]

> Unfortunately, Customer Care department do not have an email address.  You can only reach them by ﬁling your complaint via the link provided on my previous message.  14:23

So it seems that you are stuck with their form with the limited options. Just pick a random topic and then write your complaint, that's the best you can do.

Comment: I am going through that now.  I started a chat in WhatsApp and eventually got a human.  Well, it claims to be a human but it was not entirely convincing.  The latest message is: "However, I cannot guarantee that this conversation will be handled right away. I hope for your understanding."

Comment: I was also pointed back to the page in the website that I had found myself.  I insisted on a human response.

Answer (score 3):

Their [contact pages say](https://www.klm.co.uk/contact/refund-compensation/suggestion):

> You can send a compliment or give your opinion on the services offered by KLM by using the form on our complaint page.

You have to log in to see the actual form.

Comment: I have logged in and gone to that page but I am forced to select one of a few specific issues.  One option is lost baggage, which was part of the bad experience, but it assumes that the bag is still lost which it is not.

Comment: I tried several different routes through the site and general searches but I kept coming back to that same page.

Comment: OK fair enough. I registered to take a look but I can't see the form because I don't have an actual flight booking.

Comment: They [do reply to questions on Twitter](https://twitter.com/KLM_UK/with_replies) too. In [this tweet yesterday](https://x.com/KLM_UK/status/1768244749192802593?s=20) they gave other contact options for WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't have a Twitter account and I don't want to set one up just for a single complaint.

Comment: Fair enough, hopefully you can see the WhatsApp and Facebook messenger links without having to sign up if either of those work instead, (I'm slightly uncomfortable about repeating them here directly, as they're not on the KLM website as far as I can see, but they are public links I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

> My wife and I recently flew with KLM and the experience was disappointing in several ways. I would like to give some feedback but I cannot find how to do so in their website.

Sorry to be blunt or cynical, but you're probably wasting your time.  Air France-KLM is a major international publicly traded corporation.  Their job is to keep shareholders happy, not to keep travellers any happier than necessary to remain commercially successful.  They don't care if you had a disappointing experience, unless:

1. It was so bad that if it goes public and you have strong evidence, it would hurt their image and thus possibly their profits, or
2. They acted illegally, and could be held liable for €€€ unless they settle with you.

If you believe your experience meets either (or both), you can contact them using one of the ways suggested in the other answers.  If it meets (2), you could also contact a customer/traveller rights organisation to ask if they would be interested in helping you to put pressure on the airline.  If it was just one of the usual annoying-but-common ways in which airlines treat travellers, then let it go.

Comment: Yeah, I am not going to waste much time on this which is why I did not even try the phone number.  I had hoped that an email or web form would have been available to have a go with less effort.

Comment: Airlines regularly hand out frequent flyer miles for complaints, depending on what the issue was and your frequent flyer status.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to contact them both publicly or privately. For public comment, use social media platforms like on their Twitter(X) or instagram. The benefit in this would that other people would be aware about the possible situation that could happen with anyone. For private correspondence, you could call or email them or use one of the following links (whichever suits you) to give them a feedback.

https://www.klm.no/en/contact/refund-compensation/complaint

https://www.klm.no/en/contact/refund-compensation/suggestion

In the statement that you would write in the above form, you could mention your contact details if you want them to contact you.

Comment: `or email them`, What's the email address?

Comment: We might answer you better if you mention your region. Otherwise ypu can use this email address contact@klm.com

Comment: By "We" I mean the community members, who want to help you but might now due to incomplete knowledge. Also KLM has its business worldwide and one region might not service complains from another region.

Comment: Hahaha thank you for the compliment. But helping other is in my genes

Comment: I am in the UK, I added more detail to the question.

Comment: If my current WhatsApp chat comes to nothing then I will try that email - thanks.  Add it to your answer and it might be the best answer.

Comment: @badjohn The email address does not work, i got a "undelivered" response.

Comment: After a day, I have had no further response in my WhatsApp conversation.